# Send route not being found,

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, routes, mern

I am trying to use nodemailer to send an email from the contact page. I have built the site with a MERN stack. All the other routes work perfectly fine. I can setup a new user, write a post and login an existing user. The only part where the routes break is when the mail is sent on the contact page.

Below is the middleware:

```
const app = express();

// Connect Database
connectDB();

// Init Middleware
app.use(express.json());

// Define Routes
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/api/users'));
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/api/auth'));
app.use('/api/profile', require('./routes/api/profile'));
app.use('/api/posts', require('./routes/api/posts'));
app.use('/api/send', require('./routes/api/send'));
```

Below is the send route:

```
var express = require('express');
var config = require('config');
var router = express.Router();
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var cors = require('cors');

// @route   POST api/send
// @desc    Send email on contact page
// @access  Public

router.post('/send',(req, res ) => {
    var name = req.body.name
    var email = req.body.email
    var subject = req.body.subject
    var message = req.body.message
    var content = `
    name: ${name} \n 
    email: ${email} \n 
    subject: ${subject} \n 
    message: ${message} `

    var mail = {
      from: name,
      to: receiver, // receiver email,
      subject: subject,
      text: content
    }
    transporter.sendMail(mail, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        res.json({
          status: 'fail'
        })

      } else {
        res.json({
         status: 'success'
        })
      }
    })
  });

  module.exports = router;
```

I get a 404 error when I submit the form on contact page. Below is the contact page:

```
const ContactForm = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    subject: '',
    message: ''
  });

  const [result, setResult] = useState(null);

  const sendEmail = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    axios
      .post('/send', { ...state })
      .then(response => {
        setResult(response.data);
        setState({
          name: '',
          email: '',
          subject: '',
          message: ''
        });
      })
      .catch(() => {
        setResult({
          success: false,
          message: 'Something went wrong. Try again later'
        });
      });
  };

  const onInputChange = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    setState({
      ...state,
      [name]: value
    });
  };
```

This is my handler:

```
const nodemailer = require ('nodemailer');

nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.gmail.com", //replace with your email provider
    port: 587,
    auth: {
        user: process.env.email,
        pass: process.env.password
    }
}); 

// verify connection configuration
transporter.verify(function(error, success) {
    if (error) {
      console.log("error at mail send");
    } else {
      console.log("Server is ready to take the messages");
    }
  });

module.exports = transporter
```

To debug I have tried to change the POST route to
`(req, res, next)`
`(req, res, send)`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you missing transpoter object.
You need to create it with `nodemailer.createTranspot`

```
const transpoter = nodemailer.createTranspot({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'sender@gmail.com',
        pass: 'password'
    }
})
```

then try it.

Comment: I have that in my mailer.js, sorry I should have added that. I will edit to include this.

Comment: Its good you edited it. Did you turn on the **Less secure app access** for your gmail in security section.

Comment: No I never. I will make a one time account for this then,

Comment: Earlier google allowed access to this type of applications to access their mail accounts and send mails through it, but now you have to turn on it as a setting in security section. So in order to send mails through gmail account you have to turn it on to gain access to these kind of third party applications. It worked for me.

Comment: Nope that did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved by:

Moving the `transporter` to the `send route`
The route that the server is using was `api/send/send` on the `POST route`  it should be `/`